# How do I get a specific child entity from the parent agg in JPA where there could be many children

Tags: java, spring, jpa, repository-pattern

I have a 2 part question:

1. I have a root agg that has children entities and there could be a large number of them. I was looking for an efficient way to get a specific one. Right now the only way is to load them all in memory and then look through them. What I want is basically to get them by index out of the db. Is there a way to do that through the class directly without having to load all the children entities?
2. In trying to get around Q1 I made a repository method to do it, but I apparently didn't name it correctly for spring to do an automated generation. I'm using JPA/Spring and I have the following repository:

   ```
   public interface FooBarRepository extends CrudRepository<FooBar, Long>{
      SomeEntityThatIsAChildEntityOfTheRootAggFooBar findItemByFooBarAndOtherItem(FooBar foobar, OtherItem otherItem);
   }
   ```

The problem is that this doesn't work, spring throws an exception stating it can't a property called FooBar

```
FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property order found for type com.bla.foobar.FooBar
```

I've tried using 'This' and 'Id' and hoping those worked, but neither of them worked either.

I tried to use the JPQL to get it, but that doesn't work either because the child entity doesn't have knowledge of it's parent, although the child entity table does actually contain the FK to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Try with a native query, something like:

```
public Child findChildByIndex(Parent parent, int index) {
        return (Child) em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM childs WHERE parent_id = ?" , Child.class)
                .setParameter(0, parent.getId())
                .setFirstResult(index)
                .setMaxResults(1)
                .getResultList().get(0);
    }
```